# How does the motion of this pivot renormalize the gravitational acceleration of the bob?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism

The question is to find the equation of motion of a pendulum whose pivot point $y_s$ which is allowed to move vertically as a function of time: $y_s=y_s(t)$.
[image]

I found the equation of motion as : $ml^2\ddot\theta+ml\sin\theta[\ddot y_s+g] = 0$
At this point in the video lecture, the professor proceeds to say that "*from this equation, it is intuitive that the motion of the pivot seems to renormalize the acceleration of the point mass(gravity)*". What does this mean? 
Edit : Link to the lecture https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dL7wypLMY2Y&t=1325s

 Timestamp 21:30

Comment: Is the lecture publicly available?

Comment: yes, here you go : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dL7wypLMY2Y&t=1325s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dividing the equation of motion (EoM) that you find by $ml^2$, we obtain

$$\ddot\theta+\frac{g+\ddot y_s}{l}\sin\theta=0.$$

Compare this EoM with the one for the pendulum with the pivot fixed:

$$\ddot\theta+\frac{g}{l}\sin\theta=0.$$

*Renormalize the acceleration* just means that now the pendulum does not feel a value $g$ of the acceleration of gravity, but rather $g+\ddot y_s$. It's reasonable, for example, because if the pivot were free-falling $(\ddot y_s=-g)$, then the pendulum would feel no gravity, its EoM being $\dot\theta=\rm constant$.

Probably not a very good choice of words, the word renormalization in physics is used for [other thingies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renormalization).

Comment: Yeah, I think about Quantum Mechanics whenever I see normalization lol. Thanks a bunch!!